# Find duplicates in array when there is more than one duplicated element

Tags: algorithm, duplicates

How can I find duplicates in array when there is more than one duplicated element?

When the array is only one duplicated element (for example: 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7) then it is very easy:

```c
int duplicate(int* a, int s)
{ 
    int x = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < s; ++i)
    {
        x = x ^ a[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a[s]; ++i)
    {
        x = x ^ i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

But if the input array contains more than one duplicated element (for example: 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7), the above won't work. How can we solve this problem in O(n) time?

Comment: yes, but interesting case and when the array is not sorted.

Comment: What on earth are you dong here? What are all these XOR operations for? And why the weird syntax (`*(a+s-1)` instead of `a[s-1]`)?

Comment: If you are allowed to use extra space, you can build a hash-map of value to count and then check which counts are > 1.

Comment: What does function `duplicate()` is supposed to return? currently, you're returning this value `({XOR:a[i]} XOR 1..a[s-1])` which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Khaled A Khunaifer --- certainly an element that is a duplicate, and it is written in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If space is no concern or the maximal number is quite low, you can simple use a kind of a bit-array and mark all already occurred numbers by setting the bit at the position of the number.

It'a a kind of HashSet with trivial (identity) hash-function.
Tests and set cost `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 1):

Using a set is one of the possible generic solutions. Example in c++:

```c
template <typename T>
void filter_duplicates(T* arr, int length) {
    std::unordered_set<T> set;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (set.count(arr[i]) > 0) {
            // then it's a duplicate
        }
        set.insert(arr[i]);
    }
    // the set contains all the items, unduplicated
}
```

As [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is implemented as a hash table, insertion and lookup are of amortized constant complexity. As a set can only contain unique keys, this effectively de-duplicates the items. We could finally convert back the set to an array. We could also use a map to count the occurrences.

If array elements are integers and that the maximum possible value is known, and fairly low, then the set can be replaced by a simple array either 1. of boolean or 2. of integer if we want to count the number of occurrences.